# Transactions in Monero

Tags: blockchain, transaction-data, mymonero, javascript, transactions

I need to understand and know how **transactions** work in Monero. Whether the transactions are similar or completely different from other blockchains. Also, an example javascript implementation would be helpful, I'd be really happy to see your examples and use cases.

Links, articles or libraries to learn more are welcome :)